# "nvidia/tts_en_fastpitch" not getting installed in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, text-to-speech, nvidia, huggingface

I am trying to create TTS with Nvidia NeMo tts_en_fastpitch model in python. But can not install fastpitch model. These are the errors:

```
from nemo.collections.tts.models import HifiGanModel
from nemo.collections.tts.models import FastPitchModel

spec_generator = FastPitchModel.from_pretrained("nvidia/tts_en_fastpitch")
model = HifiGanModel.from_pretrained(model_name="nvidia/tts_hifigan")
```

`[NeMo W 2023-01-21 18:49:02 optimizers:55] Apex was not found. Using the lamb or fused_adam optimizer will error out. [NeMo W 2023-01-21 18:49:03 __init__:22]` pynini`is not installed !    Please run the`nemo_text_processing/setup.sh `scriptprior to usage of this toolkit. Traceback (most recent call last):  File "c:/Users/ASROCK B560M STEEL/Desktop/nvidia tts/ntts.py", line 3, in <module> spec_generator = FastPitchModel.from_pretrained("nvidia/tts_en_fastpitch")  File "C:\Users\ASROCK B560M STEEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nemo\core\classes\common.py", line 692, in from_pretrained raise FileNotFoundError(FileNotFoundError: Model nvidia/tts_en_fastpitch was not found. Check cls.list_available_models() for the list of all available models.`

Please help me with it.

I tried code from huggingface and also from youtube. The error is same, tts_en_fastpitch is not getting installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command worked for me. it seems FastPitch is only working for this branch of that repo.

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo.git@r1.6.2#egg=nemo_toolkit[all]
```